# Android studio 3 Unable to resolve dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I update android studio to version 3.0.0 and installed gradle 4.
i create new project but **Unable to resolve dependency**.

i test this method but not working:
 - invalidate and restart
 - delete .gradle folder and build
 - clean and rebuild
 - deactive offline mode

how to fix?

details screenshots:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

[image: screenshot 4]

[image: screenshot 5]

[image: screenshot 6]

[image: screenshot 7]

Comment: Why are you using proxy servers? Try changing it to "No proxy"

Comment: @ShadabAnsari becauce my location no access t o google `dl.google....`.

Comment: Can you test whether you can make connection to `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/` using your proxy ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari oh. `Problem with connection: Status: 404`

Comment: This means your proxy server is not able to connect to google repo and that's the actual problem.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari yes is true. i'm testing with `No proxy`. please wait

Comment: @ShadabAnsari `This product is not available in your country` :| with proxy and without proxy. how to connect to google repo in android syudio? :|

Comment: Please do not post photos. Post code only. Show us your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari get success on `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom` with proxy. proxy is not my problem :|

Answer (score 1):

fixed this problem after a lot of search. in gradle.propertices file set proxy both http and https and sync again.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=12345
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1234m
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=12345
```

Answer (score -4):

use `compile` instead of `implementation`

and `testCompile` instead of `androidTestimplementation`

Comment: and instead `testImplementation` ?

Comment: use testCompile

Comment: Use `androidTestCompile` instead of `androidTestimplementation`

Comment: @MGRagab compile is deprecated with the latest gradle. Check out  this - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations

Comment: i'm testing. please wait

Comment: compile is deprecated, you should use `api`

Comment: @ShadabAnsari yes is true. is deprecated. compile not working

Comment: Yes 
Also Please refer to [Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0
](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) to know more

Comment: @ChrisStillwell please wait for test `api`

Comment: @ChrisStillwell it is problem: `Failed to download SHA1 for resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'` how to fix it?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell i test conncetion on `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/` and get response: `Problem with connection: Status: 404`

Comment: Why you suggest to use old version of gradle integration?